# Spring Roo with GAE error on most basic tests

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, maven, spring-roo

I have been playing around with [spring roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo/) for some time now, read most of the documentation, tried most of the tutorials I could find (pizze, wedding...) - all worked well. My next step was to create a basic application, that can be deployed on [Google App Engine](http://appengine.google.com/). I just can't get it to work.

I found a [simple tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-application-using) that consists of 2 Entities and seems to run fine on [GAE](http://roo-gae.appspot.com/). It has been created using Roo-1.1.0.M2. I did the exact same steps but could not get it to run. I tried Roo-1.1.0.RELEASE as well as the current Roo-1.1.1 development branch. I always ran into the same problem as [Ron](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-application-using#comment-38527).

I was able to strip down the test.roo file to

```
project --topLevelPackage com.springsource.failureexample  
persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE --applicationId failureexample
entity --class ~.domain.Person --testAutomatically
perform tests
```

Using this example, I get something like `ERROR DataNucleus.Transaction - Operation rollback failed on resource: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreXAResource` and the build fails with a test in `testCountPeople(com.springsource.failureexample.domain.PersonIntegrationTest)`.

The problem is also described at Roo's issue tracker (where I provided my minimal test script), but since it obviously worked at other setup, I might have misunderstood or overlooked something important in the setup process.

Could you provide some ideas of what my error might be?

Comment: Roo 1.1.0 GAE / GWT seems to me like a management push to "get something out there before the end of the fiscal year for PR". it has many bugs and looks more like a POC or statement of intentions rather than a tool, however, I'm checking out Roo 1.1.1 that is claimed to have some GAE and GWT improvements...

Comment: This seemed to be the answer. Using the roo-1.1.1 release, I could not reproduce the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating at least one field in your entity ?

Comment: It gave the same error so I was asuming, I could spare it for the minimal example. Only if I leave out the `--testAutomatically` then `perform tests` will finish with no errors (because there are no tests...).